# Check if first character of a string is a letter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to write a function that checks a string for multiple conditions. However, I have reached a wall when trying to figure out how to check if the first character in a string is a letter only.

```
function SearchingChallenge(str) { 

// code goes here  
let onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

if (str.length > 4 && str.length < 25){
  if (onlyLetters.test(str)){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

"u__adced_123" should return true but it's returning false. I've tried str[0]==onlyLetters but still the same.

Comment: That's because your Regex reads: "**All** characters must be letters, from start to end." Have a closer look to the caret and the dollar sign in your Regex.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you arrived at the conclusion that the RegExp pattern `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` should match the string `u__adced_123`? Nowhere in the aforementioned pattern do I see anything that would match an underscore `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onlyLetters.test(str)` checks the whole string. To get the first character, use `str.charAt(0)`.

```js
function SearchingChallenge(str) {
  let onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (str.length > 4 && str.length < 25) {
    if (onlyLetters.test(str.charAt(0))) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(SearchingChallenge('Hello World!'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('!dlroW olleH'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('u__adced_123'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const SearchingChallenge = str => (
  !!str[4] &&             // > 4
  !str[24] &&             // < 25
  (/^[a-z]+$/i).test(str) // alpha
);

// Tests...

// true: greater than four characters
console.log(SearchingChallenge('Fiver'));

// true: less than twenty-five characters
console.log(SearchingChallenge('TwentyFouroooooooooooooo'));

// false: twenty-five or more characters
console.log(SearchingChallenge('TwentyFiveooooooooooooooo'));

// false: contains numbers
console.log(SearchingChallenge('abcd1234'));

// false: less than five characters
console.log(SearchingChallenge('Four'));
```